# Why does netrw open file in a small vertical split only on the first time explorer is opened?

Tags: vim, netrw

Problem:

1. Open Vim
2. Type `:Lex` to open netrw file explorer and open a file in a vertical split using `v`
3. As you can see in the image below, the space allocated to the split is tiny.
4. This **only** happens on the first time netrw file explorer is opened. If I close the file explorer and follow step 2 again and open a file again using `v`, I get the expected behaviour as shown in the 2nd image below.

**.vimrc settings:**

```
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_altv = 1
let g:netrw_winsize = 25
noremap <C-x> :Lex<CR>
autocmd FileType netrw setl bufhidden=wipe
```

**Actual behaviour:**
[image]

**Desired behaviour:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select an open directory as working

add in your expression: `%:p:h`

- `%` - current file name
- `:p` - expand to full path
- `:h` - head (last path component removed)

### ex:

```
nnoremap <leader>dd :Lexplore %:p:h<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:Iexplore` sets the `g:netrw_chegwin` variable so that all subsequent `:Explore` split commands will also open the selected buffer on the same window as `:Lexplore`

If you use `:Lex`, the variable `g:netrw_chegwin` gets set to `2`, and even after you close the :Flex window, the variable remains set.

So if, for example you use `:Sex` after using `:Lex`, the file that you select will open in the window that was being used by `:Lex`, which is probably not what you want.

To make `:Explore` splits behave as they normally do, you can reset by:

```
let g:netrw_chgwin = -1
```